# How to draw a square shape with a character and a random number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a square box of a letter depending on the size the user enters. For example, if the user enters number `5` and character `'o'`, draw a shape as follows:

```
ooooo
o   o
o   o
o   o
ooooo
```

Or if user enters number `3` and character `'h'`, draw a square with `'h'` character like following:

```
hhh
h h
hhh
```

I'm new to javascript so I don't know how to do this at all. Remember I have to print it on the screen not on `console.log`. I would like to learn from my assignment by reading your code and understanding your logic. So I can have better logic for future assignments.

Comment: What units of measurements are you using? When you say `n = 5`, it's 5 of... what? And what have you tried?

Comment: From my understanding the unit is `o` :-)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Also read [How do I ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Output to screen is a separate issue. If you can console log it you can fill a div with CSS set to pre too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. What you want is on any line that isn't the first or the last to only "draw" an `o` at the start and at the end. To make sure the spacing is correct on all the other lines, we still draw `o` but with opacity 0.

```js
function generateBox() {
  const number = document.querySelector('#boxSize').value;
  let html = [];
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (i === 0 || i === number - 1) {
      for (j = 0; j < number; j++) html.push("<span>o</span>");
    } else {
      html.push("o")
      for (j = 0; j < number - 2; j++)
        html.push("<span style='opacity:0'>o</span>");
      html.push("<span>o</span>");

    }
    html.push("<br/>");
  }
  document.querySelector('#box').innerHTML = html.join('');
}

document.querySelector('#generateBox').addEventListener('click', generateBox);
```

```html
<label></label>
<input type="number" id="boxSize" />
<button id="generateBox">Generate box</button>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Is that the most efficient and least amount of code you can do it?

Comment: @JustinGrave What do you think could be improved? This could be a good exercise.

Comment: I think your code is good because I'm not a student so I'm not the best but she say you can use the stuff she teach to make the program. There's method like html.push and Query Selector I haven't learn yet.

Answer (score 0):

what you can try and do is to do a nested for loop and then you have an array with strings for every row

```js
let n = 5;

let output = [];

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  let temp = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    temp += i === 0 || j === 0 || i === n - 1 || j === n - 1 ? "o" : " ";
  }
  output[i] = temp;
}
console.log(output)
```

It works by looping over every place a character can be and checking if it's on the edge. And if it is on the edge it adds an "o" otherwise it adds a space.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Simple Use Array.map and fill property to achieve this.

using a single condition check 
`(rowIndex === 0 || rowIndex == size-1 || colIndex === 0 || colIndex === size-1)`

```js
function MakeBox(char, size) { 
   
    Array(size).fill(char).forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        const data = Array(size).fill(char).map((column, colIndex) => { 
            if (rowIndex === 0 || rowIndex == size-1 || colIndex === 0 || colIndex === size-1) {
                return char;
            } 

            return " "

        })
        console.log(`${data.join("")}\n`);
    });
}

MakeBox("o", 5);
MakeBox("x", 10);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I was waiting for a `fill` version